# Python request cuts the post request body

Tags: java, python, http, spring-boot, python-requests

I have two applications. The first one is a python script that reads JSON data from some files and for each line (JSON object) it sends the whole line to the second application.

The second application is a spring boot API that receives the JSON line, perform some business logic and return back the JSON line with extra information.

For some JSON lines, the spring boot API does not receive the whole JSON.

Here is the python code that calls the API

```
def getNewMessage(self, message):
    s = Session()
    req = Request("POST", LOCMOJI_API, data=message)
    prepared = req.prepare()
    res = s.send(prepared)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        return res.text
    return ""
```

And here is the Spring application controller that receives the message and process it.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @Autowired
    private AnotherService anotherService;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/detect/" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public @ResponseBody String detect(@RequestBody String jsLine) {
        System.err.println("------------------------------------------");
            System.err.println(jsLine);
            System.err.println("------------------------------------------");

            // Do some business here

            return "";
    }

}
```

The following JSON will be cut down at the spring API side.

```
{
    "body": "RT @MoslawiInsights: #WATCH: Video shows Mosul's Jisr al-Rabi' (fourth Bridge) and Mosul's West coast including the districts of al-Maleya…",
    "gender": "unknown",
    "retweetCount": 1,
    "generator": {
        "displayName": "Twitter Web Client",
        "link": "http://twitter.com"
    },
    "sentiment": "neu",
    "twitter_filter_level": "low",
    "postedTime": "2017-01-10T00:21:47.000Z",
    "favoritesCount": 0,
    "object": {
        "body": "#WATCH: Video shows Mosul's Jisr al-Rabi' (fourth Bridge) and Mosul's West coast including the districts of al-Male… ",
        "verb": "post",
        "generator": {
            "displayName": "Twitter Ads",
            "link": ""
        },
        "twitter_filter_level": "low",
        "favoritesCount": 0,
        "object": {
            "postedTime": "2017-01-10T00:13:54.000Z",
            "objectType": "note",
            "link": "http://twitter.com/MoslawiInsights/statuses/818566491515678720",
            "id": "object:search.twitter.com,2005:818566491515678720",
            "summary": "#WATCH: Video shows Mosul's Jisr al-Rabi' (fourth Bridge) and Mosul's West coast including the districts of al-Male… "
        },
        "actor": {
            "followersCount": 60926,
            "preferredUsername": "MoslawiInsights",
            "friendsCount": 90,
            "displayName": "Mohammed",
            "links": [{
                "rel": "me"
            }],
            "twitterTimeZone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
            "favoritesCount": 136,
            "statusesCount": 39956,
            "summary": "Mouslawi | مصلاوي",
            "languages": ["en"],
            "utcOffset": "-28800",
            "link": "http://www.twitter.com/MoslawiInsights",
            "location": {
                "displayName": "مقر قيادة الموساد | Mossad HQ",
                "objectType": "place"
            },
            "id": "id:twitter.com:462293420",
            "verified": false,
            "listedCount": 91,
            "postedTime": "2012-01-12T23:01:41.000Z",
            "image": "",
            "objectType": "person"
        },
        "twitter_lang": "en",
        "twitter_entities": {
            "symbols": [],
            "user_mentions": [],
            "hashtags": [{
                "indices": [0, 6],
                "text": "WATCH"
            }],
            "urls": [{
                "indices": [117, 140],
                "url": "",
                "expanded_url": "",
                "display_url": "twitter.com/i/web/status/8…"
            }]
        },
        "long_object": {
            "body": "#WATCH: Video shows Mosul's Jisr al-Rabi' (fourth Bridge) and Mosul's West coast including the districts of al-Maleya and al-Jawsaq ",
            "display_text_range": [0, 131],
            "twitter_extended_entities": {
                "media": [{
                    "expanded_url": "",
                    "sizes": {
                        "small": {
                            "h": 191,
                            "resize": "fit",
                            "w": 340
                        },
                        "large": {
                            "h": 576,
                            "resize": "fit",
                            "w": 1024
                        },
                        "medium": {
                            "h": 338,
                            "resize": "fit",
                            "w": 600
                        },
                        "thumb": {
                            "h": 150,
                            "resize": "crop",
                            "w": 150
                        }
                    },
                    "url": "",
                    "media_url_https": "http_link",
                    "video_info": {
                        "aspect_ratio": [16, 9],
                        "duration_millis": 115440,
                        "variants": [{
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/vid/1280x720/buUgbb_U8sVQK-Ij.mp4",
                            "bitrate": 2176000,
                            "content_type": "video/mp4"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/pl/XuPg7S0yg9YOWlo-.m3u8",
                            "content_type": "application/x-mpegURL"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/pl/XuPg7S0yg9YOWlo-.mpd",
                            "content_type": "application/dash+xml"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/vid/640x360/duBhSamczOIc0ZAB.mp4",
                            "bitrate": 832000,
                            "content_type": "video/mp4"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/vid/320x180/sHYQewgSXlhhI_KV.mp4",
                            "bitrate": 320000,
                            "content_type": "video/mp4"
                        }]
                    },
                    "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/qQfjYKelXu",
                    "id_str": "818564172929581056",
                    "indices": [132, 155],
                    "type": "video",
                    "id": 818564172929581000,
                    "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/818564172929581056/img/7TiW8IO73UgkTO9y.jpg"
                }]
            },
            "twitter_entities": {
                "symbols": [],
                "media": [{
                    "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/MoslawiInsights/status/818566491515678720/video/1",
                    "sizes": {
                        "small": {
                            "h": 191,
                            "resize": "fit",
                            "w": 340
                        },
                        "large": {
                            "h": 576,
                            "resize": "fit",
                            "w": 1024
                        },
                        "medium": {
                            "h": 338,
                            "resize": "fit",
                            "w": 600
                        },
                        "thumb": {
                            "h": 150,
                            "resize": "crop",
                            "w": 150
                        }
                    },
                    "url": "",
                    "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/818564172929581056/img/7TiW8IO73UgkTO9y.jpg",
                    "video_info": {
                        "aspect_ratio": [16, 9],
                        "duration_millis": 115440,
                        "variants": [{
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/vid/1280x720/buUgbb_U8sVQK-Ij.mp4",
                            "bitrate": 2176000,
                            "content_type": "video/mp4"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/pl/XuPg7S0yg9YOWlo-.m3u8",
                            "content_type": "application/x-mpegURL"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/pl/XuPg7S0yg9YOWlo-.mpd",
                            "content_type": "application/dash+xml"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/vid/640x360/duBhSamczOIc0ZAB.mp4",
                            "bitrate": 832000,
                            "content_type": "video/mp4"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/vid/320x180/sHYQewgSXlhhI_KV.mp4",
                            "bitrate": 320000,
                            "content_type": "video/mp4"
                        }]
                    },
                    "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/qQfjYKelXu",
                    "id_str": "818564172929581056",
                    "indices": [132, 155],
                    "type": "video",
                    "id": 818564172929581000,
                    "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/818564172929581056/img/7TiW8IO73UgkTO9y.jpg"
                }],
                "hashtags": [{
                    "indices": [0, 6],
                    "text": "WATCH"
                }],
                "user_mentions": [],
                "urls": []
            }
        },
        "link": "http://twitter.com/MoslawiInsights/statuses/818566491515678720",
        "provider": {
            "displayName": "Twitter",
            "link": "http://www.twitter.com",
            "objectType": "service"
        },
        "display_text_range": [0, 140],
        "postedTime": "2017-01-10T00:13:54.000Z",
        "id": "tag:search.twitter.com,2005:818566491515678720",
        "objectType": "activity"
    },
    "actor": {
        "followersCount": 217,
        "preferredUsername": "blooddragon911",
        "friendsCount": 284,
        "displayName": "bloodwolf911",
        "links": [{
            "rel": "me"
        }],
        "favoritesCount": 19009,
        "statusesCount": 28783,
        "summary": "oooh (-_-)  I'm a scary socialist!! I tweet about social justice, but i also tweet other things that interest me, things i 'm passionate about, and i love Anime",
        "languages": ["en"],
        "link": "http://www.twitter.com/blooddragon911",
        "location": {
            "displayName": "Shangri La ",
            "objectType": "place"
        },
        "id": "id:twitter.com:714289549908832256",
        "verified": false,
        "listedCount": 117,
        "postedTime": "2016-03-28T06:14:34.379Z",
        "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/714290288882278401/oJ1EyzcD_normal.jpg",
        "objectType": "person"
    },
    "twitter_lang": "en",
    "twitter_entities": {
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [{
            "indices": [3, 19],
            "id_str": "462293420",
            "screen_name": "MoslawiInsights",
            "id": 462293420,
            "name": "Mohammed"
        }],
        "hashtags": [{
            "indices": [21, 27],
            "text": "WATCH"
        }],
        "urls": []
    },
    "verb": "share",
    "link": "http://twitter.com/blooddragon911/statuses/818568473873772545",
    "provider": {
        "displayName": "Twitter",
        "link": "http://www.twitter.com",
        "objectType": "service"
    },
    "gnip": {
        "klout_profile": {
            "link": "http://klout.com/user/id/159877818884456090",
            "topics": [{
                "displayName": "Middle East",
                "topic_type": "influence",
                "score": 1,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/7076043128808508468",
                "id": "7076043128808508468"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Iraq",
                "topic_type": "influence",
                "score": 1,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/7895679606907690580",
                "id": "7895679606907690580"
            }, {
                "displayName": "International Heads of State",
                "topic_type": "influence",
                "score": 1,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/10000000000000018360",
                "id": "10000000000000018360"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Turkey",
                "topic_type": "influence",
                "score": 1,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/8055202137854805987",
                "id": "8055202137854805987"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Syria",
                "topic_type": "influence",
                "score": 1,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/4870724842089262213",
                "id": "4870724842089262213"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Syria",
                "topic_type": "interest",
                "score": 1,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/4870724842089262213",
                "id": "4870724842089262213"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Twitter",
                "topic_type": "interest",
                "score": 0.93,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/10000000000000008253",
                "id": "10000000000000008253"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Middle East",
                "topic_type": "interest",
                "score": 0.91,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/7076043128808508468",
                "id": "7076043128808508468"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Iraq",
                "topic_type": "interest",
                "score": 0.89,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/7895679606907690580",
                "id": "7895679606907690580"
            }],
            "klout_user_id": "159877818884456090"
        },
        "klout_score": 44,
        "matching_rules": [{
            "tag": "mosulenglishpart120161201",
            "id": 804313992667787300
        }],
        "profileLocations": [{
            "displayName": "La Plata, Buenos Aires, Argentina",
            "objectType": "place",
            "geo": {
                "type": "point",
                "coordinates": [-57.95453, -34.92145]
            },
            "address": {
                "country": "Argentina",
                "region": "Buenos Aires",
                "subRegion": "Partido de La Plata",
                "countryCode": "AR",
                "locality": "La Plata"
            }
        }]
    },
    "id": "tag:search.twitter.com,2005:818568473873772545",
    "objectType": "activity"
}
```

Here is the result of the print statement from the spring controller

```
{
    "body": "RT @MoslawiInsights: #WATCH: Video shows Mosul's Jisr al-Rabi' (fourth Bridge) and Mosul's West coast including the districts of al-Maleya…",
    "gender": "unknown",
    "retweetCount": 1,
    "generator": {
        "displayName": "Twitter Web Client",
        "link": "http://twitter.com"
    },
    "sentiment": "neu",
    "twitter_filter_level": "low",
    "postedTime": "2017-01-10T00:21:47.000Z",
    "favoritesCount": 0,
    "object": {
        "body": "#WATCH: Video shows Mosul's Jisr al-Rabi' (fourth Bridge) and Mosul's West coast including the districts of al-Male… ",
        "verb": "post",
        "generator": {
            "displayName": "Twitter Ads",
            "link": ""
        },
        "twitter_filter_level": "low",
        "favoritesCount": 0,
        "object": {
            "postedTime": "2017-01-10T00:13:54.000Z",
            "objectType": "note",
            "link": "http://twitter.com/MoslawiInsights/statuses/818566491515678720",
            "id": "object:search.twitter.com,2005:818566491515678720",
            "summary": "#WATCH: Video shows Mosul's Jisr al-Rabi' (fourth Bridge) and Mosul's West coast including the districts of al-Male… "
        },
        "actor": {
            "followersCount": 60926,
            "preferredUsername": "MoslawiInsights",
            "friendsCount": 90,
            "displayName": "Mohammed",
            "links": [{
                "rel": "me"
            }],
            "twitterTimeZone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
            "favoritesCount": 136,
            "statusesCount": 39956,
            "summary": "Mouslawi | مصلاوي",
            "languages": ["en"],
            "utcOffset": "-28800",
            "link": "http://www.twitter.com/MoslawiInsights",
            "location": {
                "displayName": "مقر قيادة الموساد | Mossad HQ",
                "objectType": "place"
            },
            "id": "id:twitter.com:462293420",
            "verified": false,
            "listedCount": 91,
            "postedTime": "2012-01-12T23:01:41.000Z",
            "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/815445760690962432/1QZO4C8W_normal.jpg",
            "objectType": "person"
        },
        "twitter_lang": "en",
        "twitter_entities": {
            "symbols": [],
            "user_mentions": [],
            "hashtags": [{
                "indices": [0, 6],
                "text": "WATCH"
            }],
            "urls": [{
                "indices": [117, 140],
                "url": "",
                "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/i/web/status/818566491515678720",
                "display_url": "twitter.com/i/web/status/8…"
            }]
        },
        "long_object": {
            "body": "#WATCH: Video shows Mosul's Jisr al-Rabi' (fourth Bridge) and Mosul's West coast including the districts of al-Maleya and al-Jawsaq",
            "display_text_range": [0, 131],
            "twitter_extended_entities": {
                "media": [{
                    "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/MoslawiInsights/status/818566491515678720/video/1",
                    "sizes": {
                        "small": {
                            "h": 191,
                            "resize": "fit",
                            "w": 340
                        },
                        "large": {
                            "h": 576,
                            "resize": "fit",
                            "w": 1024
                        },
                        "medium": {
                            "h": 338,
                            "resize": "fit",
                            "w": 600
                        },
                        "thumb": {
                            "h": 150,
                            "resize": "crop",
                            "w": 150
                        }
                    },
                    "url": "",
                    "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/818564172929581056/img/7TiW8IO73UgkTO9y.jpg",
                    "video_info": {
                        "aspect_ratio": [16, 9],
                        "duration_millis": 115440,
                        "variants": [{
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/vid/1280x720/buUgbb_U8sVQK-Ij.mp4",
                            "bitrate": 2176000,
                            "content_type": "video/mp4"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/pl/XuPg7S0yg9YOWlo-.m3u8",
                            "content_type": "application/x-mpegURL"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/pl/XuPg7S0yg9YOWlo-.mpd",
                            "content_type": "application/dash+xml"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/vid/640x360/duBhSamczOIc0ZAB.mp4",
                            "bitrate": 832000,
                            "content_type": "video/mp4"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/vid/320x180/sHYQewgSXlhhI_KV.mp4",
                            "bitrate": 320000,
                            "content_type": "video/mp4"
                        }]
                    },
                    "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/qQfjYKelXu",
                    "id_str": "818564172929581056",
                    "indices": [132, 155],
                    "type": "video",
                    "id": 818564172929581000,
                    "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/818564172929581056/img/7TiW8IO73UgkTO9y.jpg"
                }]
            },
            "twitter_entities": {
                "symbols": [],
                "media": [{
                    "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/MoslawiInsights/status/818566491515678720/video/1",
                    "sizes": {
                        "small": {
                            "h": 191,
                            "resize": "fit",
                            "w": 340
                        },
                        "large": {
                            "h": 576,
                            "resize": "fit",
                            "w": 1024
                        },
                        "medium": {
                            "h": 338,
                            "resize": "fit",
                            "w": 600
                        },
                        "thumb": {
                            "h": 150,
                            "resize": "crop",
                            "w": 150
                        }
                    },
                    "url": "",
                    "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/818564172929581056/img/7TiW8IO73UgkTO9y.jpg",
                    "video_info": {
                        "aspect_ratio": [16, 9],
                        "duration_millis": 115440,
                        "variants": [{
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/vid/1280x720/buUgbb_U8sVQK-Ij.mp4",
                            "bitrate": 2176000,
                            "content_type": "video/mp4"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/pl/XuPg7S0yg9YOWlo-.m3u8",
                            "content_type": "application/x-mpegURL"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/pl/XuPg7S0yg9YOWlo-.mpd",
                            "content_type": "application/dash+xml"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/vid/640x360/duBhSamczOIc0ZAB.mp4",
                            "bitrate": 832000,
                            "content_type": "video/mp4"
                        }, {
                            "url": "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/818564172929581056/vid/320x180/sHYQewgSXlhhI_KV.mp4",
                            "bitrate": 320000,
                            "content_type": "video/mp4"
                        }]
                    },
                    "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/qQfjYKelXu",
                    "id_str": "818564172929581056",
                    "indices": [132, 155],
                    "type": "video",
                    "id": 818564172929581000,
                    "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/818564172929581056/img/7TiW8IO73UgkTO9y.jpg"
                }],
                "hashtags": [{
                    "indices": [0, 6],
                    "text": "WATCH"
                }],
                "user_mentions": [],
                "urls": []
            }
        },
        "link": "http://twitter.com/MoslawiInsights/statuses/818566491515678720",
        "provider": {
            "displayName": "Twitter",
            "link": "http://www.twitter.com",
            "objectType": "service"
        },
        "display_text_range": [0, 140],
        "postedTime": "2017-01-10T00:13:54.000Z",
        "id": "tag:search.twitter.com,2005:818566491515678720",
        "objectType": "activity"
    },
    "actor": {
        "followersCount": 217,
        "preferredUsername": "blooddragon911",
        "friendsCount": 284,
        "displayName": "bloodwolf911",
        "links": [{
            "rel": "me"
        }],
        "favoritesCount": 19009,
        "statusesCount": 28783,
        "summary": "oooh (-_-)  I'm a scary socialist!! I tweet about social justice, but i also tweet other things that interest me, things i 'm passionate about, and i love Anime",
        "languages": ["en"],
        "link": "http://www.twitter.com/blooddragon911",
        "location": {
            "displayName": "Shangri La ",
            "objectType": "place"
        },
        "id": "id:twitter.com:714289549908832256",
        "verified": false,
        "listedCount": 117,
        "postedTime": "2016-03-28T06:14:34.379Z",
        "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/714290288882278401/oJ1EyzcD_normal.jpg",
        "objectType": "person"
    },
    "twitter_lang": "en",
    "twitter_entities": {
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [{
            "indices": [3, 19],
            "id_str": "462293420",
            "screen_name": "MoslawiInsights",
            "id": 462293420,
            "name": "Mohammed"
        }],
        "hashtags": [{
            "indices": [21, 27],
            "text": "WATCH"
        }],
        "urls": []
    },
    "verb": "share",
    "link": "http://twitter.com/blooddragon911/statuses/818568473873772545",
    "provider": {
        "displayName": "Twitter",
        "link": "http://www.twitter.com",
        "objectType": "service"
    },
    "gnip": {
        "klout_profile": {
            "link": "http://klout.com/user/id/159877818884456090",
            "topics": [{
                "displayName": "Middle East",
                "topic_type": "influence",
                "score": 1,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/7076043128808508468",
                "id": "7076043128808508468"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Iraq",
                "topic_type": "influence",
                "score": 1,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/7895679606907690580",
                "id": "7895679606907690580"
            }, {
                "displayName": "International Heads of State",
                "topic_type": "influence",
                "score": 1,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/10000000000000018360",
                "id": "10000000000000018360"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Turkey",
                "topic_type": "influence",
                "score": 1,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/8055202137854805987",
                "id": "8055202137854805987"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Syria",
                "topic_type": "influence",
                "score": 1,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/4870724842089262213",
                "id": "4870724842089262213"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Syria",
                "topic_type": "interest",
                "score": 1,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/4870724842089262213",
                "id": "4870724842089262213"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Twitter",
                "topic_type": "interest",
                "score": 0.93,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/10000000000000008253",
                "id": "10000000000000008253"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Middle East",
                "topic_type": "interest",
                "score": 0.91,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/7076043128808508468",
                "id": "7076043128808508468"
            }, {
                "displayName": "Iraq",
                "topic_type": "interest",
                "score": 0.89,
                "link": "http://klout.com/topic/id/7895679606907690580",
                "id": "7895679606907690580"
            }],
            "klout_user_id": "159877818884456090"
        },
        "klout_score": 44,
        "matching_rules": [{
            "tag": "mosulenglishpart120161201",
            "id": 804313992667787300
        }],
        "profileLocations": [{
            "displayName": "La Plata, Buenos Aires, Argentina",
            "objectType": "place",
            "geo": {
                "type": "point",
                "coordinates": [-57.95453, -34.92145]
            },
            "address": {
                "country": "Argentina",
                "region": "Buenos Aires",
                "subRegion": "Partido de La Plata",
                "countryCode": "AR",
                "locality": "La Plata"
            }
        }]
    },
    "id": "tag:search.twitter.com,2005:81856847387377254
```

You will notice that the JSON is cut down at the id field.

I changed the maximum request size in spring API to be 10MB but the situation is the same.

Comment: If I use your python code to send the json sample to http://httpbin.org/post the response shows that the json has been sent without being truncated.  Are you certain that `requests` is truncating the message, rather than something in the target application, or something in between the two?

Comment: No, I am not sure where the root cause is. I tried to call the spring API using a rest client addon of google chrome and it receives the request correctly. That is why I suspected the python side.

Comment: Maybe you need to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`?  For example `req = requests.Request('POST', LOCMOJI_API, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data=message)`

Comment: I tried this but it did not work.